# Totally ordered set. Defining a subset and a Least upper bound

Tags: order-theory

Ok, so I have 2 problems i've been working on and I want to see if I'm anywhere close to getting it right. Pretty new to the whole abstract math scene.

The problems are defined as: X,≤ is a totally ordered set which is not empty. a,b ∈ X and  a < b, the open interval (a,b) is defined by

(a, b) = {x ∈ X : a < x < b}

1) Show that if c < a and b < d then (a,b)⊆(c,d)

2) Assume that {(an, bn)}n∈N is a growing set of open intervals i.e. an+1 ≤ and  bn ≤ bn+1. Assume that there are elements c, d ∈ X such that c ≤ an og bn ≤ d for all n. Show that if (X, ≤) has the least upper bound property then S
n∈N (an, bn) is an open interval. Show by example that this conclusion do not have to be right if (X, ≤) lacks the least upper bound property.

I'll try and keep this short. Now for 1) I started by showing that (a,b)R(c,d) is reflexiv, antisymmetric and transative. **Reflexive** is pretty straight forward. for **antisymmetric** I used

(a, b) = {x ∈ X : a < x < b}

(c, d) = {x ∈ X : c < x < d}

So for a value x (a,b)=(c,d) (first trace of doubt here)

**Transitive**

c < a and b < d

e < c and d < f

e < a and b < f

Is this enough? In my mind showing the relation is pretty much stating that they are both sets in X, and given that c < a and b < d then (c,d) then (a,b)⊆(c,d).

For 2) I have that for (X,≤) you have the set S = {b ≤ b2 ≤ ... bn+1} then d carries all the properties it requires to be upper bound of S and using that I can show that bn+1 carries the properties of the least upper bound.

for the last part of the question I assumed that if n goes towards infinity then there can be no upper bound our least upper bound properties.

Sorry for the length of this, I tried to keep it as short as possible by skipping a few steps. I just want to find out if I'm getting anywhere closer at all to cracking the code here.

Comment: for 1): HUH?? You apparently have completely misunderstood what is being asked for here. $(a,b)$ is a set. $(c, d)$ is a set. All you have to show is that everything in the set $(a,b)$ is also in the set $(c,d)$. There is no relation being defined. You don't have to show any relational properties. You just need to apply the relational properties of $<$ that have been given.

Comment: You are mostly right about #1 but your writing and notation is ... sloppy. (sorry).  By transitivity c < a < b < d so if x is such a < x < b then it follows by transitivity c < a < x < b < d so c < x < d so every x is (a, b) is also in (c, d) so (a, b) is a subset of (c, d).  I'd like to help you with #2 and I'm sure I can but I don't understand the question.  Can you retype it?

Comment: For 2) $d$ does not "carry all the properties it requires to be an upper bound of $S$". The phrase is just "$d$ is an upper bound of $S$". More particularly, though is that in general $b_{n+1}$ is *not* an upper bound of $S$, much less the least upper bound. $b_{n+1}$ is an element of $S$, and as the $b_n$ are increasing, we can generally expect $b_{n+2}$ to be greater than $b_{n+1}$. There is a least upper bound, which we can call $\hat{b}$, but in general $\hat{b}$ does not need to be in $S$.

Comment: d is an upper bound of all $b_n$ because it is larger than all $b_n$.  $b_{n+1}$ is a) not a specific value as n is variable but b) $b_{n+1}$ =< $b_{n + 2}$ so there is no reason to think it is an upper bound.  The subtlety, though, is *you don't have to find the least upper bound*.  You just have to know that it exists.  There *is* one and you can call it b.  You don't have to know what it is in relation to any $b_n$ or any thing else.

Comment: "... if n goes towards infinity then there can be no upper bound our least upper bound properties. "

That's not what that means.  {$b_n$} *doesn't* go to infinity because d is larger than all $b_n$, so {$b_n$} *IS* bounded above.  But if X doesn't have a the l.u.b property it doesn't follow that there is a smallest upper bound.  The real numbers do have the l.u.b. prop so there isn't any real example, but the rational numbers don't so there is.  All rational numbers whose square is less than 2 is bound above.  But there is no smallest rational number that is larger than all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question I think you are right on both of these.

1)  if x is in (a,b) then

x > a; a > c so by transitivity x > c.

x < b; b < d so by transitivity x < d.

So c < x < d.  so x is in (c, d) for all points of x in (a, b). So (a, b) is a subset of (c, d).

2)  Your notations and typing was a bit hard to read but I'm assuming the question is asking:

If $(a_n, b_n);$ n in N so that $a_0 > a_1 > ...  $ and $b_0 < b_1 < ...  $ which inductively by the above problem mean the are nested subsets (or "growing as you put it"). Assume there are c and d where c <= $a_n$ and d  >= $b_n$ for all $a_n$ and $b_n$. Show that if X has the least upper bound property then the union of all ($a_n$, $b_n$) is an open interval (a, b) for some numbers a and b.  Show this need not be true if X doesn't have the least upper bound property.

Is this right?

You are on the right track Since c <= $a_n$ for all $a_n$ {$a_n$} is bounded bellow and has an greatest lower bound.  Call it a.  Similarly since d >= $b_n$ for all $b_n$, {$b_n$} is bounded above and has a least upper bound.  Call it b.

As all $a_n$ >= a an all $b_n$ <= b, ($a_n$, $b_n$)⊆(a,b) and the Union of all such ($a_n$, $b_n$) is a subset of (a, b).

If x is in (a, b), the a < x < b.  As a is inf{$a_n$}, x is not a lower bound of {$a_n$} so there is an a <= $a_j$ < x.  Likewise there exists a x < $b_k$ < b.  Let n = max(j, k).  So a <= $a_n$ <= $a_j$ < x < $b_n$ <= $b_j$ <= b.  So x is in ($a_n, $b_n).  So (a, b) is a subset of the union.

So (a, b) is the union.

Okay... so why wouldn't that be true if X doesn't have the least upper bound property?  Well, there might not be any a and b that are extreme bounds.  For example;  If X is the rational numbers (which doesn't have the least upper bound property) and {$a_n$} are a decreasing sequence of rational number heading toward $\sqrt{2}$ and {$b_n$} are a sequence of rational numbers heading toward $\sqrt{3}$, then the union will be all the rational numbers between $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ but this is *not* an open interval for any (a, b) as there are no possible rational endpoints.